# Turning a object of functions into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Say we have on object like so :

```
myObj = {
  function1 : function(d){return d+1;},
  function2 : function(d){return d+2;},
  function3 : function(d){return d+3;}
}
```

How can I convert this object into an array of such objects :

```
{name : "function1", func: function()}
```

where `function()` is a real function ?

Comment: Where are you going to get 'name' from?

Comment: `Object.entries()` does not convert the functions into strings.

Comment: btw you can't have `{name : "name", function: function()} `, you can have `{name : "name", func: function()} `

Comment: did you mean `name: function1` and so on?

Comment: `Object.values` is what you looking for I believe

Comment: @MinusFour then how would the names be determined? Despite what the OP wrote in the question, `Object.entries()` is the correct answer. (Well, part of the correct answer.)

Comment: Note that when you `console.log()` the result of the transformation, the console will helpfully print out the function bodies. They're not really strings however, as you could determine with a `typeof` test.

Comment: This statement `converts the functions into strings.` generates a lot of confusion.

Comment: Sorry, the first edit didn't include the keys of the object, so I thought `values` was enough

Comment: @Pointy you are right, it doesn't. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` on the `Object.entries()`

```js
const myObj = {
  function1 : function(d){return d+1;},
  function2 : function(d){return d+2;},
  function3 : function(d){return d+3;}
}

const arr = Object.entries(myObj).map(([name, func]) => ({name, func}));

console.log(arr)
```

If you note I used `func` instead of `function` that't because `function` is a reserved keyword and you can't name a variable `function`. If you want to use that name you can use below code.

**Note:** Don't use `function` or any other reserved keyword as property name. Because you won't be able to destructure it using the same name.

```js
const myObj = {
  function1 : function(d){return d+1;},
  function2 : function(d){return d+2;},
  function3 : function(d){return d+3;}
}

const arr = Object.entries(myObj).map(([name, func]) => ({name, function: func}));

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You're getting a syntax error, I think because StackOverflow's system doesn't understand destructuring

Comment: @TKoL No that's because `function` is reserved keyword.

Comment: Yes, you can have a property name "function" but it'd have to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myObj = {
  function1 : function(d){return d+1;},
  function2 : function(d){return d+2;},
  function3 : function(d){return d+3;}
}

const arr = [];
for (const key in myObj) {
    arr.push({ 
        name: key, 
        func: myObj[key]
    })
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

````
const myObj = {
 function1 : function(d){return d+1;},
 function2 : function(d){return d+2;},
 function3 : function(d){return d+3;}
}
const result = Object.keys(myObj).map(elem=>({name:elem,func:myObj[elem]}))
```.
````